# Is it possible to create a user from one Org to another automatically?

Tags: user-management, user-record

I am trying to Create an Org to manage all of the user records for a POC. So from my POC org I have an Object called **People** (can also be the user record) and have a related list called **Org Access** (List of orgs that the particular user/people have access to).

So from that single org when a People record is Created, a user is created from another org automatically based on the Org Access related list.

I am trying to find out if there would be any configurable solution to this if possible. Though, any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *configuragble* solution for this. You will need to utilize APIs (SOAP or REST) here to be able to create User in any Org. If you choose REST, then you will have to consider [additional things](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) for it. On top of this, you will need to make sure that you have an admin User available in all of the other Orgs which will be used by your APIs and which has sufficient permission  to be able to create a user.

The following resources will help you to get started in that direction:

- [User Object SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm)
- [Create Records using REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm)
- [REST API Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm)